# Consumir web-service em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-service

Preciso de consumir alguns métodos na minha página através de um Web-Service. Este Web-Service está na Europa.

Qual é a melhor forma de o fazer? O que são End-Points?

Comment: Caro @pnet, se você não resolveu de nenhuma dessas formas mas resolveu de outra, então por favor, poste como resolveu. Caso tenha resolvido seguindo alguma das respostas dadas, por favor, então marque como resposta aceita a que te ajudou a resolver o problema. Obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

Segundo o site http://www.ehow.com/info_12212371_definition-service-endpoint.html, um *endpoint* é definido no texto traduzido abaixo:

> Um *endpoint* é um ponto de conexão de onde os arquivos HTML ou dinâmicos estão expostos. Endpoints fornecem informações necessárias para acessar um *Webservice*. O *endpoint* fornece uma referência ou especificação que é usada para definir um grupo ou família de propriedades  de endereçamento de mensagens e dar características da mensagem ponto-a-ponto, como referências para a origem eo destino dos terminais, bem como a identidade de mensagens para permitir endereçamento uniforme de mensagens "independentes". O *endpoint* pode ser um PC, PDA, ou terminal de ponto-de-venda.

No seu caso, o *endpoint* é o próprio endereço do WebService que se deseja acessar.

Para adição de um WebService na sua aplicação, faça o seguinte:

### Passo 1

Botão direito no projeto > <kbd>Add</kbd> > <kbd>Service Reference</kbd>

[image: Passo 1]

### Passo 2

Nesta tela, clique em <kbd>Advanced</kbd>

[image: Passo 2]

### Passo 3

Clique em <kbd>Add Web Reference...</kbd>

[image: Passo 3]

### Passo 4

Cole o endereço do WebService que deseja acessar no campo *URL*. Se for mesmo um WebService com uma WSDL válida, os métodos aparecerão no quadrado de baixo. Basta clicar em <kbd>Add Reference</kbd> que será adicionado ao seu projeto uma classe que representa o acesso ao WebService.

[image: Passo 4]

## Consumindo o WebService

Para acessar os dados do seu WebService em Controller, use uma declaração mais ou menos assim:

```
var wsMeuWebService = new wsMeuWebService.MeuWebService();
wsMeuWebService.MetodoDoWebService();
```

Comment: Uso o Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @pnet Atualizada.

Comment: @pnet, parece-me que esta resposta é totalmente válida. Se for, marca como correta.

Comment: Para mim generate task-based operation esta desabilitado... isso pode interferir em algo?

Comment: As operações não são tratadas como assíncronas, simplesmente. Se sua aplicação é assíncrona pode até interferir, mas não chega a ser um problema.

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte, clique com o botão direito no projeto e escolha a opção `Adicionar referência de serviço`.

Cole a URL do WS, mude o namespace e aperte em OK.

Comment: Legal e agradeço pelo tuto que envuou. A minha dúvida é essa. O WS tem 3 end-points. Veja o tuto dos caras. Para você poder efetuar as operações de Pesquisa, Reserva, Pagamento, Consulta de Files, entre outras, você precisa de ter uma sessão no webservice. 
As sessões são criadas pelo método CreateSession(), disponível no endpoint Common. O retorno desse método é uma string, que passaremos a chamar de sessionId. Esse sessionId é necessário em praticamente todos os métodos do Webservice.
O método CreateSession() recebe um objeto do tipo UserAuthTokensV1.

Comment: Estou seguindo o exemplo de vocês. A dúvida é, preciso carregar o resultado no cshtml, via jquery e ajax, para evitar carregar a page toda. Como eu faço? Toda dúvida ou a maior parte dela está aí. No jquery

Comment: Em realidade é o seguinte. Esse método vai me trazer um array de strings ou objetos, não sei ainda, mas acho que é string. Preciso fazer um each em jquery e ir populando nos lugares corretos. Se vir mais de um item, ir criando DIV's e colocando o texto e no menu à direita, ir montando um link. Em realidade é um array de hotéis, categorias, num quartos e as categorias(estrelas) ir montando no painel à direita. Isso é que eu preciso fazer com jquery.

Comment: Então me esclarece uma coisa, você não quer chamar ele em código, quer chamar o Web Service via Ajax, certo?

Comment: Sim. Já até comecei a fazer minha jquery. Só o esqueleto, assim: function PegaHotelPacote() {

    $.ajax({

        url: '/Passo/PegaHotelPacote',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        sucess: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (error) {

        }

    });
}. O meu método na controller é que tá osso, mas falta mais informação do gestor. Jogou no ar e se mandou.